# Filtering Bokeh LabelSet with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a Bokeh scatterplot with a CheckboxGroup widget to show or hide individual points based on the corresponding checkbox state.  The code snippet below works to create a checkbox for each point, and the Javascript works to show or hide the respective points in the scatterplot based on changes to checkbox states.  The problem is that I also need to label each point in the scatterplot.  A LabelSet works fine to do this.  Unfortunately, the labels on the scatterplot will not show or hide in sync with their respective scatterplot points.  LabelSet does not accept a view argument, so the means of filtering the scatterplot with a CDSView does nothing for the labels.  All the labels stay visible all the time.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
active = list(range(len(df))
filter = IndexFilter(indices=active)
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[filter])

p=figure(.....)
p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, view=view)

labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='label', source=source)
p.add_layout(labels)

labelList = df['label'].astype(str).to_list()
labelSel = CheckboxGroup(labels=labelList, active=active)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(src=source, filt=filter), code='''
    filt.indices = cb_obj.active
    src.change.emit()
    ''')
labelSel.js_on_change('active', callback)

layout = row(p, Spacer(width=20), labelSel)
show(layout)
```

I'm looking for some help in finding a way to filter the LabelSet CDS in sync with the scatterplot CDS as filtered by an IndexFilter driven by a CheckboxGroup.  I expect that there is some Javascript that could make this happen, possibly with a separate CDS for the LabelSet, but I'm not good enough with Javascript to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do what I need.  It seems ugly and inefficient, but it works.  I created a second CDS for the LabelSet and then used JS to rebuild the data in that CDS from the main CDS using the CheckboxGroup states.  Please still feel free to respond if you have a much cleaner and more elegant way to do this.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
lsource = ColumnDataSource(df)
active = list(range(len(df))
filter = IndexFilter(indices=active)
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[filter])

p=figure(.....)
p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, view=view)

labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='label', source=lsource)
p.add_layout(labels)

labelList = df['label'].astype(str).to_list()
labelSel = CheckboxGroup(labels=labelList, active=active)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(src=source, lsrc=lsource, filt=filter), code='''
    filt.indices = cb_obj.active;
    src.change.emit();

    var data=src.data;
    var l=data['label'];
    var x=data['x'];
    var y=data['y'];

    var ldata=lsrc.data;
    var a=cb_obj.active;

    var ll=[];
    var lx=[];
    var ly=[];
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        ll.push(l[a[i]]);
        lx.push(x[a[i]]);
        ly.push(y[a[i]]);
    }

    ldata['label']=ll;
    ldata['x']=lx;
    ldata['y']=ly;
    lsrc.change.emit();
    ''')
labelSel.js_on_change('active', callback)

layout = row(p, Spacer(width=20), labelSel)
show(layout)
```